# Excel export and import in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

is it possible to export an excel file from its path in the database then edit its content like some sort of edit form and import it back as an excel file path.
is there like faster way or a method i can use? or is it even possible to trick the users into thinking that they are editing a live-edit form but its just and excel form? 
the reason why i need this, is because i want say for example a faculty member to evaluate students. but the evaluation form fields are too much to store in the database and the fields and the evaluation criteria may be changed in the future.
what would you suggests me doing at this case?

what i did so far is ask faculty members to upload their evaluations as an excel sheet. and then extract the final grade. and store only the final grade in the database. however, this is not what my client wants.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are libraries for working with Excel files, I think you should develop a dynamic evaluation framework. This way you won't have any problem with future changes. The downside is you not only have to store all evaluation form fields, but you should also store all possible answers. Actually, you need several Table to develop this scenario.